# laravel sync method with uuid

Tags: php, laravel, uuid

I have 2 tables `categories` and `posts` and third table `category_posts` is pivot table to relate those two tables.

#### Issue

The problem is that I use `uuid` for my tables and when new row will add to `category_posts` it does not get `uuid` so second row will throw error as ids aren't unique (both are empty).

What I'm looking for is a way to add `uuid` in my sync method.

```
$post->categories()->sync($request->input('category_id'), false);
```

and `uuid` package I use is `goldspecdigital` which can generate new `uuid` with this code

```
\Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid::uuid4()->toString()
```

#### Question

How can I add generating uuid code into my sync method in order to create uuid for each row as they are adding to database?

**PS**

I have tried such code but obviously wasn't successful so I'm asking here :)

```
$post->categories()->sync([['id' => \Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid::uuid4()->toString()], $request->input('category_id'), false]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this:

```
$category_ids = (array) $request->input('category_id');

foreach( $category_ids as $category_id ) {
   $data_to_sync[ $category_id ] = [ 'id' => \Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid::uuid4()->toString() ];
}

$post->categories()->sync( $data_to_sync, false );
```

this is basically a way you pass additional data to a pivot table via the sync method. But I'm not sure if it works for primary id.

let me know if it doesn't work